# Android: Problems getPixels from Bitmap

Tags: android

I have the following code...

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test, options);
int[] pixels = new int[1];
if(b != null){
  pixels = new int[b.getHeight()*b.getWidth()];
  b.getPixels(pixels, 0, b.getWidth(), 0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight());
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++){
    Log.d("test","Pixel is :"+pixels[i]);
  }
}
```

R.drawable.test is a .bmp file in the res/drawable-nodpi dir

but instead of the 0-255 values I would expect it looks more like this...

```
06-03 21:49:24.364: D/test(4088): Pixel is :-16777088
06-03 21:49:24.364: D/test(4088): Pixel is :-16777088
06-03 21:49:24.364: D/test(4088): Pixel is :-16777088
06-03 21:49:24.364: D/test(4088): Pixel is :-16777088
06-03 21:49:24.364: D/test(4088): Pixel is :-16777088
06-03 21:49:24.364: D/test(4088): Pixel is :-16777088
06-03 21:49:24.374: D/test(4088): Pixel is :-16777088
```

That number doesn't look right at all, can someone help me with what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert your pixels to RGB

Here is a code sample

```
             int[] pix = new int[picw * pich];
             bitmap.getPixels(pix, 0, picw, 0, 0, picw, pich);

             int R, G, B, Y;

             for (int y = 0; y < pich; y++) {

                 for (int x = 0; x < picw; x++)
                     {
                     int index = y * picw + x;
                     int R = (pix[index] >> 16) & 0xff;     //bitwise shifting
                     int G = (pix[index] >> 8) & 0xff;
                     int B = pix[index] & 0xff;

                     //R, G, B - Red, Green, Blue
                     //to restore the values after RGB modification, use 
                     //next statement

                     pix[index] = 0xff000000 | (R << 16) | (G << 8) | B;

                    }
            }
```

Comment: What about a png and adding alpha, does this change for that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845646/how-to-write-png-files-in-java-using-pixel-rgb-values-0-to-1  something like said here